# how to apply values of two arrays?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Generally: how do I take two arrays and apply a single function that iterates over both of them simultaneously and updates their values?

Specifically:

I have a list of buttons and a list of positions, created via something like this:

```
let buttons:Array<Button> = makeButtons();
let positions:Array<number> = R.scan(
  (total, width) => total + width, 
  0, 
  R.map(button => button.width, buttons));
```

How do I now take the list of positions, and apply them to the buttons?

Related to this is something I'm additionally confused about - is there a technique to control whether the modification is happening on the button itself vs. returning a new button with the same "shape" as the input?

I'd imagine there are scenarios where I'd want to do either of those (e.g. if modifying existing buttons on the screen without needing to redraw them, vs. staying more pure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`zipWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith):

```
zipWith((but, pos) => assoc('position', pos, but), buttons, positions)
```

Notice that `scan` as used here will give one more element than is included in the original list: the first element is the initial value of the accumulator.  But `zipWith` stops when the smallest list is exhausted.  Depending upon whether you want to include that first value or the last one, you might have to add a call to `tail`.  (I imagine here that position would be the left-hand side of the buttons, and it wouldn't be necessary.)

Note also that you're rewriting some functions that come with Ramda in this:

```
let positions = R.scan(
  (total, width) => total + width, 
  0, 
  R.map(button => button.width, buttons));
```

You could get the same results with

```
let positions = R.scan(R.add, 0, R.pluck('width', buttons))
```

Now, you could also did this with a single fold, if you choose, by using a slightly more complex accumulator:

```
R.compose(R.prop('buttons'), R.reduce((all, curr) => {
  const buttons = append(assoc('position', all.pos, curr), all.buttons);
  const pos = all.pos + curr.width;
  return {pos, buttons}
}, {pos: 0, buttons: []}))(buttons)
```

This would build your structure in a single pass through the data.  I wouldn't actually recommend this here.  It's a technique I use when I really want to avoid intermediate structures or multiple iterations through a list, but it's an interesting alternative.

You can see all this in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20buttons%20%3D%20%5B%7Bheight%3A%2050%2C%20width%3A%2070%7D%2C%20%7Bheight%3A%2050%2C%20width%3A%20125%7D%2C%20%7Bheight%3A%2060%2C%20width%3A%2090%7D%5D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2A%0Alet%20positions%20%3D%20R.scan%28%0A%20%20%28total%2C%20width%29%20%3D%3E%20total%20%2B%20width%2C%20%0A%20%200%2C%20%0A%20%20R.map%28button%20%3D%3E%20button.width%2C%20buttons%29%29%3B%0A%2A%2F%0A%0Aconst%20positions%20%3D%20R.scan%28R.add%2C%200%2C%20R.pluck%28%27width%27%2C%20buttons%29%29%3B%0A%0AzipWith%28%28but%2C%20pos%29%20%3D%3E%20assoc%28%27position%27%2C%20pos%2C%20but%29%2C%20buttons%2C%20positions%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20zipWith%28%28but%2C%20pos%29%20%3D%3E%20%7Bbut.position%20%3D%20pos%3B%20return%20but%7D%2C%20buttons%2C%20positions%29%3B%0A)**.

---

Regarding this:

> Related to this is something I'm additionally confused about - is there a technique to control whether the modification is happening on the button itself vs. returning a new button with the same "shape" as the input?

Ramda's philosophy is to **never** modify your input.  So if you use something like [`R.assoc`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc), you will always get back something new.  And Ramda will not try to duplicate its inheritance hierarchy.  If you want to modify the buttons in place, my first suggestion is to reconsider, as Ramda's reasons are sound, but if you still want to, then just change the first suggestion above to

```
zipWith((but, pos) => {but.position = pos; return but}, buttons, positions);
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation, and thanks for the recipes! Will get cookin later :) I added a separate followup to the last point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573496/approach-to-modifying-values

Comment: Also - can you explain a bit or point me somewhere that explains a "fold"? I see in your example of "a single fold" you didn't actually use Ramda's unfold()

Comment: `reduce` is a fold.  At one point Ramda used `fold` and `reduce` as aliases.  When we dropped aliases, we (eventually) lost `fold`, as `reduce` is so embedded in the language, and in certain specifications.  But it's the same concept: take a collection of items that one can visit in sequence, a function that combines two of them into a single one, and an initial value, and return a new value that combines them using that value and the function.

Comment: is there a short list of functions that are potentially unsafe? map() is always giving back something new, assoc() too... but zipWith is potentially dangerous... or is it something that comes second nature when you've used this stuff for a while? :)

Comment: @davidkomer: not sure what you're looking for here.  What do you mean by "unsafe" in this context?

Comment: nm - I see now, zipWith is returning a shallow copy no matter what happens inside of it, but if inside of it you modify a property of an object directly it will modify that object directly

Comment: @davidkomer: Yes, but that's true for `map` and others like it too.  The callback is supplied your value.  You can return whatever you like: the original value, the original value with altered properties, a clone of the original value with or without alterations, or something altogether different.  None of these return your original *container*, but the values inside it are under your control.

Comment: Any idea if Sanctuary or another JS lib can prevent that sort of tampering?

Comment: Well, remember that the one you'd be protecting yourself from is you!  Sanctuary has the same thing.  You could use something like Immutable on its own or with Ramda for this.  Or if you had handy a useful `clone` function, it's easy enough to write your own `map`, etc. that uses it to avoid this possibility.  but then, remember that this would often really reduce performance for no real gain in functionality, just some protection against your ever doing something that perhaps one day you might actually want to do.

Comment: gotcha - will look into Immutable. Thanks for your taking the time to answer these followup questions!