# Approach to modifying mutable objects?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, pixi.js, ramda.js

Given that functional programming is best when sticking to immutable variables as much as possible, and that Ramda always makes shallow copies, how are objects that *must* be mutable dealt with in a mostly-purely functional framework?

For example, consider PIXI.Sprite (in pixi.js). The display system has an inherent hierarchy that is linked together and has its own way of tracking objects so it can re-use textures, etc. Garbage collecting them could be a real problem.

What sort of approaches can be taken to deal with this (alongside a robust frp system like sodium-typescript)?

Specifically, can this approach be improved:

1. Having some sort of unsafePerformIO() function that will modify the heavy objects. All modification of those objects is only done through that function.
2. Lightweight meta-information objects carry all the logic around.
3. Those lightweight information objects reference the heavy objects directly

Here is a full code sample in Typescript to demonstrate it in action (just need to import PIXI and Ramda). The key lines are in gameLoop():

```
let app = new PIXI.Application(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(app.view);


let ball = new PIXI.Graphics();
ball.beginFill(0xFF0000);
ball.drawCircle(0,0,40);
ball.endFill();

ball.y = app.stage.height/2;

app.stage.addChild(ball); //app

let ticker = new PIXI.ticker.Ticker();
ticker.add(gameLoop);
ticker.start();

let ballReference = {
    ptr: ball,
    x: 0
}

function performUnsafeIO(reference) {
    reference.ptr.x = reference.x;
}
function gameLoop(deltaTime:number) {
    //this version breaks!
    //ball = R.assoc('x', ball.position.x + deltaTime * 1, ball);

    //This works fine... but are there any gotchas?
    ballReference = R.assoc('x', ballReference.x + deltaTime * 1, ballReference);
    performUnsafeIO(ballReference);
}
```

(note, this conversation found via Google is a good reference point: https://web.archive.org/web/20100410001213/http://itmmetelko.com/blog/2008/02/23/functional-programming-immutable-objects-explained-irc-style/)

Comment: An interesting question, but not really within the SO guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: I think you could improve the quality of this ( already good) question through providing a small snippet that expresses your question with code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll try to see if I can demonstrate the problem more clearly with code

Comment: Look into functional lenses, especially the `set` and `mapOver` operations. Here is the obligatory link to [DrBoolean](https://github.com/DrBoolean/lenses).

Comment: @ftor - thanks, will read!

Comment: And the technique you're actually looking for is called [persistent data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure). Lenses can give you a very primitive form of persistence in this sense.

Comment: @ScottSauyet and Jonasw (hrm so only lets me tag one user in a comment)- I've updated the question and provided a code sample. Thanks for the push - made it much clearer for me too!

Comment: Dont know pixi, just some guessing, couldnt you do: ballReference=Object.create(ball,{x:0}); so you dont need performUnsafeIO anymore?

Comment: it seems that only instantiates a new ball, it doesn't link that new object's getters and setters to affect the old one

Comment: I have the same question, its required in cases like this. Although it goes against the principle of purity and FP in general.